how can i toggle unleash feature flag in integration tests in kotlin?
Unleash give this documentation - https://github.com/silvercar/unleash-client-kotlin?tab=readme-ov-file#unit-testing for writing unit tests but there is nothing on how to toggle in integration test environment. I am using mock mvc to mock the API end point and MockServerClient to mock the external dependent APIs.

This i was able to resolve using ReflectionTestUtils.setField()
  private val unleash: Unleash = mockk()
  @Autowired private lateinit var serviceImpl: ServiceImpl
  @BeforeEach
  fun beforeEach() {
    MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxed = true)
    every { unleash.client.isEnabled(Unleash.FLAG_NAME) } returns true
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(serviceImpl, "unleash", unleash)
  }

Add the above code in the integration tests which are using mock mvc.
